# (Semi-decidable) combination of first-order theories is possible in Z3, but what about an actual semantic/signature-wise combination?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, theorem-proving, first-order-logic

*Disclaimer: This is a rather theoretical question, but think it fits here; in case not, let me know an alternative :)*

**Z3 seems expressive**

Recently, I realized I can specify this type of formulae in Z3:

```
Exists x,y::Integer s.t. [Exists i::Integer s.t. (0<=i<|seq|) & (avg(seq)+t<seq[i])] & (y<Length(seq)) & (y<x)
```

Here is the code (in Python):

```
from z3 import *

#Average function

IntSeqSort = SeqSort(IntSort())

sumArray    = RecFunction('sumArray', IntSeqSort, IntSort())
sumArrayArg = FreshConst(IntSeqSort)

RecAddDefinition( sumArray
                , [sumArrayArg]
                , If(Length(sumArrayArg) == 0
                    , 0
                    , sumArrayArg[0] + sumArray(SubSeq(sumArrayArg, 1, Length(sumArrayArg) - 1))
                    )
                )

def avgArray(arr):
    return ToReal(sumArray(arr)) / ToReal(Length(arr))

###The specification

t = Int('t')
y = Int('y')
x = Int('x')
i = Int('i') #Has to be declared, even if it is only used in the Existential

seq = Const('seq', SeqSort(IntSort()))

avg_seq = avgArray(seq)

phi_0 = And(2<t, t<10)
phi_1 = And(0 <= i, i< Length(seq))
phi_2 = (t+avg_seq<seq[i])

big_vee = And([phi_0, phi_1, phi_2])

phi = Exists(i, big_vee)


phi_3 = (y<Length(seq))
phi_4 = (y>x)

union = And([big_vee, phi_3, phi_4])

phiTotal = Exists([x,y], union)

s = Solver()
s.add(phiTotal)
print(s.check())
#s.model()
solve(phiTotal) #prettier display
```

We can see how it outputs `sat` and outputs models.

**But...**

However, even if this expressivity is useful (at least for me), there is something I am missing: *formalization*.

I mean, I am combining first-order theories that have different signature and semantics: a *sequence-like* theory, an integer arithmetic theory and also a (uninterpreted?) function *avg*.  Thus, I would like to combine these theories with a Nelson-Oppen-like procedure, but this procedure only works with quantifier-free fragments.

I mean, I guess this combined theory is semi-decidable (because of quantifiers and because of sequences), but can we formalize it? In case yes, I would like to (in a correct way) combine these theories, but I have no idea how.

**An exercise (as an orientation)**

Thus, in order to understand this, I proposed a simpler exercise to myself: take the decidable *array property fragment* (What's decidable about arrays?http://theory.stanford.edu/~arbrad/papers/arrays.pdf), which has a particular set of formulae and signature.

Now, suppose I want to add an *avg* function to it. How can I do it?

- Do I have to somehow combine the array property fragment with some kind of recursive function theory and an integer theory? How would I do this? Note that these theories involve quantifiers.
- Do I have to first combine these theories and then create a decision procedure for the combined theory? How?
- Maybe it suffices with creating a decision procedure within the array property fragment?
- Or maybe it suffices with a syntactic adding to the signature?

Also, is the theory array property fragment with an avg function still decidable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-answer answer: Start by reading Chapter 10 of https://www.decision-procedures.org/toc/

A short answer: Unless your theory supports quantifier-elimination, SMT solvers won't have a decision-procedure. Assuming they all admit quantifier-elimitation, then you can use Nelson-Oppen. Adding functions like `avg` etc. do not add significantly to expressive power: They are definitions that are "unfolded" as needed, and so long as you don't need induction, they're more or less conveniences. (This is a very simplified account, of course. In practice, you'll most likely need induction for any interesting property.)

If these are your concerns, it's probably best to move to more expressive systems than push-button solvers. Start looking at Lean: Sure, it's not push-button, but it provides a very nice framework for general purpose theorem proving: https://leanprover.github.io

Even longer answer is possible, but stack-overflow isn't the right forum for it. You're now looking into the the theory of decision procedures and theorem-proving, something that won't fit into any answer in any internet-based forum. (Though https://cstheory.stackexchange.com might be better, if you want to give it a try.)

Comment: Thanks again! First of all, what I understand is that, since  the array property fragment and the linear integer arithmetics are decidable, they admit quantifier-elimination and, thus, are Nelson-Oppen combinable? As for 'avg', this is the part in which I get lost because you say that, as long as induction is not there, they add no significant expressive power; however... if I add 'avg', which is defined recursively, does not that automatically add induction? In other words: is property fragment + integer arithmetic + avg decidable?

Comment: I am interested in push-botton-like solvers, because they are not the end, but part of a bigger system that needs full automation :) However, I am slowly learning their limits. I will explore Lean, as long as it allows some automation (general purpose means some automation?) :) I have to thank you again!

Comment: If your proof doesn't need induction, then you can always "unfold" the definition some fixed number of times. That's why adding recursive definitions doesn't add much, since they can be unfolded. This, however, won't work if you need induction. (As it would amount to infinite unfolding, intuitively.)

Comment: Lean allows a ton of automation. In fact, most theorem provers are really about automation via tactics. They come with a ton, and you develop your own tactics to automate most of the proofs.

Comment: Hmm.. in the case of the 'avg' function, this could be "unfolded" finitely if we knew the length of the sequence. But, since this length is not fixed, I guess its definition needs induction.

Comment: Exactly. Consequence: If you add a constraint to limit the length of the sequence to some concrete number, z3 should be able to prove most any property about it. (If not, that might be something you should report so developers can look at it.)